# spring-cloud configserver exclude root application.yml

Tags: spring-cloud, configserver

we like to use the spring cloud configserver to get the configuration of an application.

the repo has a root **application.yml** and a folder with **application-myapp/myapp.yml**

is there a possibility to skip the content of the application.yml for a request and only show the content of the application-myapp.yml?

wget http://xxx:xxx@configserver:1337/test/myapp-default.yml

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can utilize search-pattern in configuration:

```
repos:
            perf:
              pattern:
              - '*/perf'
              uri: ***
              search-paths:
              - 'myapp*'
```